# Do you create all object references in the main class or in the appropriate relationship class?

Tags: java, oop, object, class-design

I have my main class **PayUnit** where I create my main object references, such as **touchScreen**, **scale**, and **barcodeReader** as these are `has-a` relationships to my **PayUnit**. This machine also `has-a` **billDispenser** but **billDispenser** is really 'is-a' relationship to **currencyDispener**. Do I still create a **billDispenser** and **currencyDispenser** object references in the main class, or do  create a **currencyDispenser** reference in **PayUnit** and then create a **billDispenser** in the **currencyDispenser** class?

I hope that makes sense. What is the standard for OOP in this regard?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, it appears that there's no need to have the references to both `billDispenser` and `currencyDispenser` in `PayUnit` (since they are not separate entities, and one of them is an implementation of the other). A common practice is to define a protocol (an interface or an abstract class in Java) that describes the API of a module (in your case, `currencyDispenser`), and then have a factory method somewhere provide an implementation that conforms to that interface (`billDispenser` in your case). I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I see, so only references to concrete classes, more or less?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question, but it's preferable to use the references to the superclass whenever possible. Then you can replace the concrete class with another one, and it will just work. In your example, `PayUnit` can have a reference to `CurrencyDispenser`, and you can assign it an instance of `BillDispenser` or, say, `CoinDispenser`, all without any changes to `PayUnit`.